# sed - Remove lines that contain "hotmail" in the third field

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to delete all emails that contain the word hotmail in the third field from my .txt file. I am currently trying to use the following but it only deletes some lines. I am not sure why

```
sed -i '/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*hotmail/d' *.txt
```

Below is one of the lines that where not removed

```
"field1","field2.","email@hotmail.com","whoeditedoutn.com","NeditedoutOW.COM|NeditedoutW.COM","editedout",""
"foo,bar","baz,qux","email@hotmail.com","whoeditedoutn.com","NeditedoutOW.COM|NeditedoutW.COM","editedout",""
```

Could someone give me the correct command please? Also if possible a command that word with both upper case and lower case `hotmail` or `HoTmAiL` or any other variant.

Comment: That command worked fine with above line, can you give full input?

Comment: How can I give you that? Sorry I am new

Comment: @Teddy291 Write it in the question.

Comment: The file is too large I printed some lines http://pastebin.com/DgZ4w33T if you run that line 17 still has hotmail

Comment: @Teddy291 Thats because it's not the thrid field on that line as the second one contains a comma,you will likely need to use a CSV parser to get consistent accurate results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a CSV file, fields 1 and 2 may contain commas. Thus regular expression matching will not work. You need a proper CSV parser. Here's an example

```
ruby -rcsv -ne 'row = CSV::parse_line($_); puts $_ unless row[2] =~ /hotmail/i' file
```

**update**: that ruby command indeed does not alter the file. Neither does your sed command above. To save the changes back to the file, use the `-i` option. With your pastebin data:

```
wc -l file
ruby -rcsv -i -ne 'row = CSV::parse_line($_); puts $_ unless row[2] =~ /hotmail/i' file
wc -l file
```

```
  22 file
  20 file
```

---

Perl also has a CSV module, not standard though, [get it from CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) -- error handling not implemented

```
perl -MText::CSV -le '
  $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary=>1, always_quote=>1 });
  open $fh, "<", shift(@ARGV);
  while ($row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    $csv->print(STDOUT, $row) unless $row->[2] =~ /hotmail/i;
  }
' file
```

Comment: Hello, this did not work sorry. I tested it with http://pastebin.com/DgZ4w33T input. Also I am doing this for lots of files so I would rather it not print all the text on screen

Comment: So did I. It output 20 lines, removing the 2 hotmail entries on lines 17 and 20.

Comment: Not for me :( do I need anything else installed other than ruby? I am using CentOS 6

Comment: Probably not.  "csv" is part of the standard library. What version of ruby do you have?

Comment: I just tried it on my Ubuntu VPS also and it did not work. ruby 1.8.7 and ruby 1.9.3p484. The file is a .txt but I also tried converting to csv and it still doesn't remove

Comment: "did not work" -- worst problem description ever. What did happen?

Comment: Nothing, the file did not change. It just printed all the contents into my putty screen

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25155/discussion-between-teddy291-and-glenn-jackman).

Comment: I get the following error on Ubuntu 12.04 version 1.9.3p484  - /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1914:in `block (2 levels) in shift': Missing or stray quote in line 1 (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1887:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1887:in `block in shift'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1849:in `loop'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1849:in `shift'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1396:in `parse_line'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'

Comment: "Missing or stray quote" -- that's a data problem -- fix your malformed CSV data.

Comment: The same files work with CentOS 6 - Something is missing with Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Also ruby seems to be much much slower than sed - Could you help give me the same command but with sed?

Answer (score 2):

As you asked for a `sed` solution,

```
sed -n -e '/^"[^,]*","[^"]*",".*@hotmail/Ip' file
```

Here I am just printing the lines that would be deleted. revert to your original options to do exactly what you want. change `/Ip` to `/Id` and change `-n` back to `-i`

`/I` provides case insensitive search

The second field uses `[^"]` instead of not comma so that fields with commas inside are not split.

and I have added the quotes onto the fields and added @ before domain name to make it look more like an email address.

Update: This version ensures that @hotmail.com is followed by 2 email addresses. ie is first on the line.

This searches for a hotmail address at third column

```
sed -n -e '/^"[^"]*","[^"]*",".+@hotmail.com",.+@.+,.+@.+$/Ip' file
```

This one for hotmail any where in third col so works with your test data in pastebin.

```
sed -n -e '/^"[^"]*","[^"]*",".*hotmail.+",.+@.+,.+@.+$/Ip' file
```

Update2:

I've simplified the regex to :

```
sed -n -e '/^("[^"]*",){2}"[^"]*hotmail[^"]*"/Ip'
```

Comment: sed -n -e '/^"[^,]*","[^"]*",".*@hotmail/Ip output.txt' returns the error sed: -e expression #1, char 34: extra characters after command

Comment: sorry, I added `file` incorrectly during my paste, will correct.

Comment: Thank you. That worked by showing the lines that have hotmail but I removed -n and replace /Ip with /Id but that just printed everything, it did not remove any lines containing hotmail - sed -e '/^"[^,]*","[^"]*",".*@hotmail/Id' output.txt was the full command

Comment: arh, You originally used -i option to edit in place, add `-i` (I like to keep original and create a new file so that I can diff just to check what has gone on.)

Comment: Thank you but that also delete "hotmail" lines that are not in the email field (third??). For example if the last field was hotmail but the email field was not a hotmail address that line would also be deleted.

Comment: ok, so then we want to add another field match after hotmail and probably an eol anchor.

Comment: How can we add that? Just to confirm if you look at http://pastebin.com/3kSw6kv7 then only the first line should be deleted. It has "hotmail" in the third field which is the only field this should check for

Comment: sed -i -e '^"[^"]*","[^"]*",".*hotmail.+",.+@.+,.+@.+$/Id' text.txt is returning sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `^'

Comment: That was a typo from a mis paste, all the sed commands have started with a /

Answer (score 1):

Using [csvkit](http://csvkit.rtfd.org/):

```
csvgrep -c 3 -i -r '(?i)hotmail' file.csv
```

This assumes `file.csv` has a header line.